# PHP:Assigning the value of a variable to a tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to execute a command through the shell_exec() function and then assign the execution value to a javascript tag but I am facing a problem with the javascript

PHP code

```
$result=shell_exec("dir");
    echo <<<"go"
    <script>document.getElementById("pre").innerHTML="$result"</script>;
    go;
```

HTML code

```
<div id="cmd"><pre id="pre"></pre></div>
```

The JavaScript problem that appears when executing the code is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: https://ideone.com/mPjVi9

Comment: This is not a javascript problem. You have wrong declaration of heredoc (it should be without quotes around go here: <<<go). You can use simple concatenation, interpolation or sprintf. Example (interpolation, worst performance but simplest): echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"pre\").innerHTML=\"$result\"</script>;". Please note backslash inside double quoted string. Instead you can use single quote inside double, or use sprintf